# Ubuntu 18.04 + two network scanners

Tags: networking, drivers, 18.04, scanner, samsung

I have problems with using Samsung scanners connected via network. The issue is that in one physical location I'm using Samsung SCX-3200W printer/scanner, in a second one SCX-3405W (never both at the same time). Searching different forums I've executed the following steps (it may happen that not all were necessary):

1. I've installed drivers from HP page uld_V1.00.39_01.17
2. I've modified /etc/sane.d/xerox_mfp.conf adding IPs

> ```
> #Samsung SCX-3200 Series, Samsung SCX-3205W
> tcp 192.168.1.240
> tcp 192.168.8.200
>
> #Samsung SCX-3400 Series
> tcp 192.168.1.240
> tcp 192.168.8.200
> ```

plus I've executed

```
sudo ln -sfr /usr/lib/sane/libsane-smfp* /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane

sudo adduser $USER lp
sudo apt install libusb-0.1-4
```

Unfortunately it didn't work.

After many attempts I've discovered that using only one IP address works, so ex:

```
#Samsung SCX-3200 Series, Samsung SCX-3205W
tcp 192.168.1.240


#Samsung SCX-3400 Series
tcp 192.168.1.240
```

Is there any chance to add more that one IP address to make system searching which scanner is active? I've tried both simple scan and xsane.